# Probability - Tales Game

Tags: probability, combinatorics, dice

A dice game played by two players is like this: each player throws two dice and sum their results; that is the number of points the player scored. Whoever scores more, wins.

One additional detail is that if the numbers of both dice of a player are equal, the player can roll the two dice again and the sum of these points will be added to the previous sum - and so on, indefinitely.

```
  A) A player has k points. Calculate his probability of victory.
  B) A group of friends decided to play the same game with n players.
       Find the winning probability for a player who scored k points.
```

I've tried for some time to do this, but it seems impossible to me. I don't know much of this kind of probability. Does anyone know a way to solve this problem?

Comment: try to add some info as to what you have tried and where the question is from. Copy-Pasting the question is generally not a good way to get the answer you need.

Comment: A player's result is the sum of a series of doubles ($\frac 56$ of the time none) followed by a non-double throw.  You can calculate the probability distribution of the non-double throw by deleting some cases from the usual 36 of two dice.  Calculating the expectation of the series of doubles is not hard, it is only 1.4 points.  I don't see a neat way to get the exact distribution, but the generating function experts can probably do so.  Then you can add the two distributions to get the distribution of a full turn.

Comment: I particularly enjoy this game, and therefore I will write down the simplest example here to explicitly show how hard the problem can be. Assume you roll a 4. That means you rolled 3&1, because 2&2 would imply you get to roll again, making you score at least 7 (you also cannot score 6 because that would be 2&2 in the 1st and 1&1 in the 2nd, which would also grant you another roll). 
So, assuming you rolled  a 4, then the only way that your opponent loses is if they roll 1&2 (again because 1&1 gives you a reroll). The probability is then $p = 2/36 = 1/18$. 

Doing this in general looks hard.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it lacks both context and clarity. (But it's an interesting question....)

Answer (score 1):

When you throw 2 dice, the sum is one of the numbers $2,3,\dots,12$. Do you know the probability of each of these sums? If you do, then you can figure out the probability of winning if you get $k$; it's the probability that your opponent gets a number less than $k$, plus half the probability that your opponent gets exactly $k$.

EDIT: For example, suppose you roll a 4. You win if your opponent rolls a 2 or a 3; the total probability of that is 1/12 (do you know why?). With probability 1/12 your opponent rolls a 4, and in that case, your probability of winning is 1/2, since you are essentially back to square one, and it is a symmetric (thus, fair) game. So your total probability of winning if you throw a 4 is $$(1/12)+(1/2)(1/12)=1/8$$

MORE EDIT: Note that the question has been edited several times since I posted the above, so the above may not speak to the current version of the question.

Comment: Sure. Suppose you are one of 7 players, and you roll a 4. You win if each of the other 6 throw 3 or less --- that's $(1/12)^6$. If they all throw 4 or less (probability $(1/6)^6$), and at least one of them throws exactly 4, then your rules don't specify whether they all get to throw again, or just the ones who threw 4 get to throw again.

Comment: I'm sorry, Lucas, I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Hello! I think you misunderstood the question. You say that, if it is k, it's 50%. That is not true, and neither is that if you take less than k you loose. Assume you get 4 (2 + 2), and k = 5. You have actually won, because you need to throw again, and now you will take a least +3 (2 + 1)...

Comment: Wrong. Supose player 1 got the numbers 5 and 6. The probably isn't 34/36 because player 2 can got 1 and 1 and win a change to roll the dices and sum the new result to the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

The probability of winning is $1-p(k)$, where $p(k)$ is the probability of losing, given that the other player rolled $k$. If a player rolled k, it is enough to compute all possible ways one can roll a total that is less than $k$, and there are finitely many possibilities, which can be easily computed.